# PuTTY + Xming + GNU screen: can it be done?

Tags: putty, gnu-screen, x11-forwarding, xming

When I connect to a remote host (running darwin) with PuTTY, and having Xming running alongside, I can run, e.g., `xlogo` on the remote host, and I see the appropriate `xlogo` display clientside.

But once I fire up GNU `screen` on the remote host, this test no longer works.  E.g. my `xlogo` command now fails with:

```
Xlib: connection to "localhost:10.0" refused by server
Xlib: PuTTY X11 proxy: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 data did not match
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

(Note that localhost:10.0 is indeed the correct value for DISPLAY.)

Is it possible to get X11 with this setup?  If so, please let me know how.

Thanks!

PS: FWIW, in PuTTY, my settings for Connection > SSH > X11 are:

- Enable X11 forwarding is CHECKED
- X display location is BLANK
- Remote X11 authentication protocol is set to MIT-Magic-Cookie-1

(Let me know if I should post any other settings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually trying to learn the basics of X11 via PuTTY last week.  I came across a nice [tutorial](http://zweije.home.xs4all.nl/xauth.html#toc9).  To be perfectly honest, as this was my first foray into X11, I didn't necessarily absorb all of the info.  I did, however, get everything working by following along.

There is a section on [this](http://zweije.home.xs4all.nl/xauth-6.html) page that dives into creating and configuring those magic cookies and setting up to use Xauth.

On the same page there, it also goes into some detail about Xhost, as @arved mentioned.  The relatively short section is quoted below...

> Xhost allows access based on hostnames. The server maintains a list of
>   hosts which are allowed to connect to it. It can also disable host
>   checking entirely. Beware: this means no checks are done, so every
>   host may connect!
>
> You can control the server's host list with the xhost program. To use
>   this mechanism in the previous example, do:
>
> `light$ xhost +dark.matt.er` This allows all connections from host
>   `dark.matt.er`. As soon as your X client has made its connection and
>   displays a window, for safety, revoke permissions for more connections
>   with:
>
> `light$ xhost -dark.matt.er` You can disable host checking with:
>
> `light$ xhost +` This disables host access checking and thus allows
>   everyone to connect. You should never do this on a network on which
>   you don't trust all users (such as Internet). You can re-enable host
>   checking with:
>
> `light$ xhost -` xhost - by itself does not remove all hosts from the
>   access list (that would be quite useless - you wouldn't be able to
>   connect from anywhere, not even your local host).
>
> Xhost is a very insecure mechanism. It does not distinguish between
>   different users on the remote host. Also, hostnames (addresses
>   actually) can be spoofed. This is bad if you're on an untrusted
>   network (for instance already with dialup PPP access to Internet).

Answer (score 1):

checkout the xhost(1) manpage for giving access control to your screen session